# Intertiajs + Vue prop not reactive in dynamic component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am dynamically creating Vue components and passing props to them using the 'component' element like so:

```
<template v-for="(element, index) in children" :key="index">
    <component :is="element.component" v-bind="element.props" />
</template>

open(){
  let component = {
    id: this.id,
    component: 'TestComponent',
    props: {
        index: this.id,
        user: this.user
    }
  }
  this.id =  this.id + 1
  this.children.unshift(component)
}
```

If I update the user component in JS, the prop is reactive and I can see the result in the component:

```
updateLocal(){
    this.user.name = 'New name'
}
```

But if I call the server using the inertia post command the prop is not updated:

```
updateServer(){
  this.$inertia.post(route('users.update'), this.user, {
    preserveScroll: true
  })
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of Inertia?

Comment: after your post request... you may want to update your props inside `onSuccess: () =>{}`

Comment: As @KimDeGuzman shared, you have to also send `onSuccess` inside the 3rd argument (with `preserveScroll`), see the [source code](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/blob/dd5902978fa457fd4f065812c747c9c743fcafc8/packages/inertia/src/router.ts#L321). Also, if I am not confused, you have to share `{ user: this.user }` and not `this.user`.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I'll try that...